# How should I use a field in views?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a CCK field that I want to use in a view. How can I do it?

Comment: Hey, consider choosing the answer as correct answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are in edit mode of your view:

1. you should have an option of adding fields
2. When you click on add field, you should see a drop down of all types of field available.
3. Choose Content from the drop down.
4. You should be able to see your cck field there, click add and review the settings for the display of the field.

   I suggest you checkout this video to get overview of views - http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode9

Comment: yse,I know , but i don't see cck field there!!!